# SQL How Many Employees Are Working, Group By Hour

Tags: sql

I have a table, a timetable, with check-in and check-out times of the employees:

```
ID    Date     Check-in     Check out
1     1-1-2011 11:00        18:00
2     1-1-2011 11:00        19:00
3     1-1-2011 16:00        18:30
4     1-1-2011 17:00        20:00
```

Now I want to know how many employees are working, every (half) hour.
The result I want to see:

```
Hour  Count
11    2
12    2
13    2
14    2
15    2
16    3
17    3
18    2,5
19    1
```

Every 'Hour' you must read as 'till the next full hour', ex. 11 -> 11:00 - 12:00

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Build an additional table, called Hours, containing the following data:

```
 h
 00:00
 00:30
 01:00
 ...
 23:30
```

then, run

```
Select h as 'hour' ,count(ID) as 'count' from timetable,hours where [Check_in]<=h and h<=[Check_out] group by h
```

Comment: The "h as 'hour'" part is backwards, and the group-by is missing on the end.

Comment: These are usually double-quotes, not single ones: `Select h as "hour"`